# Passing object in javascript function

Tags: javascript, object

Say I already have many objects, like obj1, obj2, .....obj30.....

Now I am trying to write a function like this:

```
function blar(N){
 do something to objN
} 
blar('4');
```

So far it seems that the only way to do it is

```
function blar(thisObj){
 do something to thisObj
}
blar(obj4);
```

I wonder what is the right way to pass the N such that the function can use that N value to process objN.

Hope I make myself clear.

PS: I even try something like blar(obj+N) but apparently it's wrong too, as the system tries to find obj, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Object... Number. 
Let me try that again: Object, Number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

```
window['obj' + N];
```

This depends on them dangling off the window object and not being nicely scoped though.

… but if you have a bunch of objects, which are identified by being the same except for a number, then you should probably be storing them in an array in the first place. Then you would just:

```
myArray[N];
```

Comment: Oh, why I never think of array. Thanks for the great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use eval:

```
function blar(N) {
    var obj = eval("obj"+N);
}
```

Or, if you can put those objects into an object, you can use []

```
function blar(N) {
    var obj = tracker["obj" + N];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
function blar(objectNo) {
  var obj = eval('obj' + objectNo);
  alert(obj);
}
```

To give you some keywords for talking with others about this: what you want to do is to access an object by its name, in the current scope.

But note that the following doesn't work:

```
function main() {
  var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

  blar('a'); // doesn't work
  doSomething(eval('a')); // works
}
```

This is because the variable `a` is only visible in the `main` function, but not in `blar`. That is, the `eval` must be called in a scope where the variable is visible.